# When a user input a letter it displays the hidden word and some of the loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, indentation

> Write a program to play the following game. There is a list of several country names and the
> program randomly picks one. The player then has to guess letters in the word one at a time. Before
> each guess the country name is displayed with correctly guessed letters filled in and the rest of the
> letters represented with dashes. For instance, if the country is Canada and the player has correctly
> guessed a, d, and n, the program would display -anada. The program should continue until the
> player either guesses all of the letters of the word or gets five letters wrong

Written above is the instruction to create this program.  My problem is that I cannot stop the loop and the game ends which shows the hidden country name after I put a letter.

I tried fixing the indention but still no luck.

This is my code for the program:

```
import random

def main():
    CountryList = ['india', 'canada', 'germany', 'england', 'australia', 'italy', 'ukraine']
    choice = random.choice(CountryList)

    code = [i for ele in choice for i in ele]
    index = [] #the index list

    wrong = 0 #flag variables
    win = 0

    for i in code:
        index.append(0) #adding zeros in the index list as many times as there are letters in the country name
        while(wrong != 5 and win != 1): #loop runs till you dont win or lose 5 guesses
            guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower() #user enters a letter
            j = 0
            found = 0
        for i in code:
            if guess == i:
                index[j] = 1 #if the guessed letter was found in the list then its index is noted and in that index number in the 'index' list value 1 is assigned
                found = 1 #flag that the letter was found
                j+=1
                j = 0
            if found == 1: #if the guessed letter was correct then print this
                print("Correct Guess!")
            elif found == 0:
                wrong += 1 #else number of wrong guesse increases
                print('Wrong guess! {} more wrong guess(es) left!'.format(str(5-wrong))) #and this is printed
        for i in index:
            if i == 1: #the index list is traversed
                print(code[j], end='') #if the value at any index number in the 'index' list then the letter at that very index number is printed
            elif i == 0: #otherwise'_'is printed
                print('_', end="")
                j+= 1
        for i in index:
            if not (0 in index): #checking if all the values in the 'index' list is 1
                win = 1 #if it was 1 then you win and the loop will terminate
                print('')
            if win == 1: #if you won this will be printed
                print('Congrats You won!')
            else: #otherwise this will be printed and the country name will be displayed
                print('Unfortunately you lost! Try Again.')
                print('The hidden country name was {}!'.format(choice))


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't completely understand your code, but there was a lot of unnecessary iteration, for example, you were checking `len(index)` times if the list `index` was all `1`. The code didn't stop because you were iterating all the code `len(code)**2` times due to the nested for loops. The correct code would be a hangman code, since this is a hangman problem. Code:

```
import random
word_list = ['india', 'canada', 'germany', 'england', 'australia', 'italy', 'ukraine']
chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)
display = []

# Create a list of all _ for display
for letter in chosen_word:
    display.append("_")
print(' '.join(display))

count = 0

# The code executes until the list display is all _
# So there is no need to check for it in every iteration. 
# The code for 5 tries is done using the count variable

while '_' in display and count < 6:
    print('Guess:')
    guess = input()
    k = list(chosen_word) # converting say, 'india' to ['i', 'n', 'd', 'i', 'a']

    # Checking if guessed character is in the actual word
    if guess in k:
        # Replacing underscores if the character is found
        while guess in k:
            # ''.join(k).find(guess) is the index of the character
            display[''.join(k).find(guess)] = guess
            k[''.join(k).find(guess)] = ' ' # Space for preventing repeated guesses
    else:
        # Character not found condition
        count += 1
        print('Guesses left = ', 6-count)
    print(' '.join(display))
if count >=6:
    print('You lose')
    print('The answer was: ', chosen_word)
else:
    print('You Win')
```

This is an old hangman code, you can change it as per requirements.